# Where to get IMDb datasets

Tags: data-request, economics, film

IMDb offers a great deal of useful structured information for research.

There're multiple ways to get small pieces of its database:

- Download a subset of data from http://www.imdb.com/interfaces
- Use API via http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/, https://github.com/richardasaurus/imdb-pie, or https://github.com/nandhp/python-imdb (and other languages)
- Use subsets from current papers on IMDb and its visualizations, eg this [one](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/vlado/papers/IMDBvis.pdf).
- Get a license from IMDb to use API more intensively: $15K+.
- Wandora [IMDb extractor](http://www.wandora.org/wandora/wiki/index.php?title=IMDB_extractor)
- (But not by grabbing IMDb pages, which is not allowed by IMDb.)

But these ways prevent from reaching a deeper study of relations within the DB, for instance, for economic research. Say, random sampling of a fraction of the DB may miss important relations.

Is there a better way to get mass IMDb data for research purposes?

Comment: What relations do you want to investigate, but can't?

Comment: Are you sure the data in "alternative interfaces" is a subset in the sense you're interpreting? It may just be a subset of the *kind* of data they have, but, for example, their movie list from there may be everything they have. (I suspect it is complete. For example, their movie list I downloaded now has 2,780,337 titles, which is consistent with their stats: http://www.imdb.com/stats)

Comment: I found [this copy](https://datasets.imdbws.com/) being referred to in research papers, but do not know the source.

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if this would classify as a comment or an answer, but it's useful information nonethelss:

So in reading this question I HAVE to point this out - ever heard of the paper?:

> Arvind Narayanan and Vitaly Shmatikov. **"Robust De-anonymization of Large Datasets (How to Break Anonymity of the Netﬂix Prize Dataset)".** 
>   The University of Texas at Austin February 5, 2008.

Full text is at:
http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0610105v2.pdf

It's quite a famous paper and was even on the news when it got published.

Here's the abstract:

> We present a new class of statistical de-anonymization attacks against
>   high-dimensional micro-data, such as individual preferences,
>   recommendations, transaction records and so on. Our techniques are
>   robust to perturbation in the data and tolerate some mistakes in the
>   adversary’s background knowledge. We apply our de-anonymization
>   methodology to the Netﬂix Prize dataset, which contains anonymous
>   movie ratings of 500,000 subscribers of Netﬂix, the world’s largest
>   online movie rental service. We demonstrate that an adversary who
>   knows only a little bit about an individual subscriber can easily
>   identify this subscriber’s record in the dataset. **Using the >>>Internet
>   Movie Database<<< as the source of background knowledge,** ***we successfully
>   identiﬁed the Netﬂix records of known users, uncovering their apparent
>   political preferences and other potentially sensitive information.***

I looked at their citations for clues but they only thing they cite verbatim is:

> IMDb. The Internet Movie Database. http://www.imdb.com/, 2007.

This is also quite a while ago too.  However going through the full text of that article, you may be able to glean some clues as to how they got their data and replicate those - so this could potentially help you.

Comment: +1 I think it's a useful article in many respects. Saw it some time ago. But the article's authors had to work "with a very small sample of a few dozen IMDb users" due to IMDb's limitations on crawling. **PS:** A couple ideas. (1) The Netflix dataset may be an alternative (supplement) to IMDb itself. (2) It's a potentially interesting method of revealing preferences and making sociological surveys. **PPS:** Partly relevant work about anonymous dataset and identification from [The Privacy Bounds of Human Mobility](http://www.media.mit.edu/research/groups/human-dynamics) at Media Lab.

Answer (score 1):

<del>As was alluded to in one in a comments you should check out http://www.imdb.com/interfaces which would allow you to either download manually via ftp or through a terminal interface. I am pretty sure the restrictions on the data only pertain to commercial usages but you should verify that before diving in head first.</del>  Also, you could check out http://www.themoviedb.org or http://www.omdbapi.com. themoviedb API is free but has api request limits, and it does not natively include the IMDBid in a typical search which can make integrating data from multiple sources difficult. OMDb API used to be totally free but now restricts api access though the cost for 100,000 requests is 1$/month so it is very reasonable and it does include the IMDBid in its general search.

UPDATE:

So as @lonstar, likely in order to save on costs, imdb now requires that users foot the bill for downloading by using a S3 Pay Account. However, there is a mirror site that is still operational hosted by Freie Universitat Berlin, ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pub/misc/movies/database/temporaryaccess/ .

Although, given that the name of the ftp parent directory is "temporaryaccess" it may not be long for this world. :(

Comment: looks like no more FTP - S3 requester-pays now. Also, it seems to be just titles available, not plots, stars, etc. See http://www.imdb.com/interfaces.