# IMDb users (reviews, watchlist, and ratings) dataset

Tags: data-request, film

There are several ways to get an IMDb dataset for movies, with information of title, actors and more.

However, I just want to get a dataset of the user profile and their reviews, watchlist, and ratings.

Is there any formal API for developer to fetch dataset like that or some existed dataset about users on IMDb?

Comment: Reviews don't seem to be released. See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/24839719/2327328 and here http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1073/1511

Comment: It's not the same thing, but I assume you're familiar with the large dataset Netflix released a few years ago?

Comment: @philshem I read those carefully and got some ideas. It is, however, sad to be limited to get datasets :(.

Comment: @BarryCarter maybe I should it try though.

Comment: Is it for research only? Or for commercial use? Or for something else? Answer might depend on your goal.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul research only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users-related data is not currently released.

One option could be screen-scraping, but it is forbidden by the [usage conditions](http://www.imdb.com/conditions):

> Robots and Screen Scraping: You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this site, except with our express written consent as noted below.

Comment: So it is kind of cruel when I am planning to start a research topic about recommending movies to users. Any advice in terms of data?

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but I'd simply ignore those restrictions and do it anyway. Unless IMDB finds a way to shut you down, I don't think they can legally pursue this. You almost definitely fall under the research "clause" of the Fair Use Doctorine.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am such a novice in research to be cautious about legality or other factors. Anyway, Getting data is one of the most interesting parts in research, although sometimes obstructed and tedious.